# I need help writing a Loop that finds vowels in C

Tags: c, loops

I need to prompt the user for a letter.  If that letter is not a vowel, keep prompting until a vowel is entered.

My desired outcome is:

Enter a vowel:z

That is not a vowel.  Try again:h

That is not a vowel.  Try again:w

That is not a vowel.  Try again:t

That is not a vowel.  Try again:o

Congrats.  You picked a vowel.

So far my code is:

```
do 
{
printf("Enter a vowel: ");
scanf(" %c", &letter);
}

while (letter != 'a' && letter != 'e' && letter != 'i' && letter != 'o' && letter != 'u' && letter != 'A' && letter != 'E' && letter != 'I' && letter != 'O' && letter != 'U');
{
printf("That is not a vowel. Try again: ");
scanf(" %c", &letter);    
}

printf("Congrats. You picked a vowel!!!");
```

Comment: Is that all the code? What happens when you run it? `letter` doesn't seem to have been declared.

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: Instead of this `while` that goes on forever, consider [`strchr()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr).

Comment: @tadman With [consider strchr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75342729/i-need-help-writing-a-loop-that-finds-vowels-in-c/75342767#comment132944012_75342729),  "The terminating null character is considered to be part of the string." `strchr("aeiouAEIOU", 'A')` and `strchr("aeiouAEIOU", '\0')` are both non-NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully OP will see the problem once OP's code is properly formatted.

```
  do {
    printf("Enter a vowel: ");
    scanf(" %c", &letter);
  } while (letter != 'a' && letter != 'e' && letter != 'i' && letter != 'o'
      && letter != 'u' && letter != 'A' && letter != 'E' && letter != 'I'
      && letter != 'O' && letter != 'U');

  {
    printf("That is not a vowel. Try again: ");
    scanf(" %c", &letter);
  }
```

There is no error message in the loop.

Comment: Technically the above will not give the expected output. Since the printf statement "That is not a vowel, Try again:" will be printed along with a prompt for a new letter even if you input a vowel.

Comment: @VinodA This answer is not functionally corrected code, only improved formatting to help OP to more easily see the original (and this answer's) coding error.

Answer (score 2):

Your braces, indentation and spacing are deceptive. It *looks* like the `do` has no `while` and that the `while` controls the block below it...

Try this:

```
/*...*/
    while( 1 ) {
        printf( "Enter a vowel: " );

        char letter;
        if( scanf( " %c", &letter ) != 1 )
            exit( -1 );

        if( strchr( "aeiouAEIOU", letter ) != NULL ) // found!
            break;

        printf( "That is not a vowel. Try again:\n\n" );
    }
    printf( "Congrats. You picked a vowel!!!\n" );
    // NB: 'letter' has "gone out of scope".
/*...*/
```

`strchr()` searches the string supplied for a matching character, returning NULL if it is NOT found (ie: not a vowel, in this case.)

The "infinite loop" can only "break" when the user supplies a vowel.

Add a few LFs (`\n`) to the print statements.

Comment: "an only "break" when the user supplies a vowel." --> not quite:  Pedantic: if the user _somehow_ entered a _null character_, for `letter`, then `strchr( "aeiouAEIOU", letter ) != NULL` is true.

Comment: That's why "pedantics" never get invited to parties... `:-)` Not sure if/how `scanf()` would do that for a user...

Comment: "never get invited' --> For me [I Don’t Want to Belong to Any Club That Will Accept Me as a Member](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2011/04/18/groucho-resigns/).  

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica The SO _raison d'etre_ ... `:-)` Seeking acceptance... `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

Do and While should go together. So you are looking for a code that will be something like below.
Your objective should be to ensure the user is in loop till a vowel is received. Also you can further improve the code by using functions for the vowel check. Find a sample below.

```
    do 
    {
        printf("Enter a vowel: ");
        scanf(" %c", &letter);
        if (letter != 'a' && letter != 'e' && letter != 'i' && letter != 'o' && letter != 'u' && letter != 'A' && letter != 'E' && letter != 'I' && letter != 'O' && letter != 'U')
            printf("Sorry, Try again \n");
    } while (letter != 'a' && letter != 'e' && letter != 'i' && letter != 'o' && letter != 'u' && letter != 'A' && letter != 'E' && letter != 'I' && letter != 'O' && letter != 'U');
    
    printf("Congrats. You picked a vowel!!!");
    }
```

The applicable loops in C are do-while, for and while. There is no do.

Answer (score 0):

A more concise way to achieve that would be using `strchr()`, as suggested by @tadman in the comments.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {
    char * vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";
    char letter;
    do {
        printf("Enter a vowel: ");
        scanf(" %c", &letter);
    } while (strchr(vowels, letter) == NULL);

    printf("Congrats. You picked a vowel!!!");
}
```